# OpenCV: Finding the pixel width from squares of known size

Tags: android, c++, opencv

In OpenCV I use the camera to capture a scene containing two squares **a** and **b**, both at the same distance from the camera, whose known real sizes are, say, 10cm and 30cm respectively. I find the pixel widths of each square, which let's say are 25 and 40 pixels (to get the 'pixel-width' OpenCV detects the squares as `cv::Rect` objects and I read their `width` field).

Now I remove square **a** from the scene and change the distance from the camera to square **b**. The program gets the width of square **b** now, which let's say is 80. Is there an equation, using the configuration of the camera (resolution, dpi?) which I can use to work out what the corresponding pixel width of square **a** would be if it were placed back in the scene at the same distance as square **b**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you write of "squares" with just a "width" in the image (as opposed to "trapezoids" with some wonky vertex coordinates) I assume that you are considering an ideal pinhole camera and ignoring any perspective distortion/foreshortening - i.e. there is no lens distortion and your planar objects are exactly parallel to the image/sensor plane.

Then it is a very simple 2D projective geometry problem, and no separate knowledge of the camera geometry is needed. Just write down the projection equations in the first situation: you have 4 unknowns (the camera focal length, the common depth of the squares, the horizontal positions of their left sides (say), and 4 equations (the projections of each of the left and right sides of the squares). Solve the system and keep the focal length and the relative distance between the squares. Do the same in the second image, but now with known focal length, and compute the new depth and horizontal location of square **b**. Then add the previously computed relative distance to find where square **a** would be.

Comment: Yes, it's not trapezoids I'm considering. When you say 'depth of the first/second square' in the 'first situation' do you mean distance from the camera? Because both squares are **always** the same distance from the camera. To clarify, it would be most trivial if a square of 10cm length was always half the pixel length of a square of 20cm and a third of a square of 30cm. I'm essentially trying to find an equation which will correct for the camera properties (lens distortion perhaps?) which prevent this.

Comment: Edited your question to clarify, and my answer to fix.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll mark your response as the answer but can you provide a link to something on the web, some tutorial perhaps, which explains your answer in greater detail?

Comment: Google for "antonio criminisi phd thesis", which pretty much covers anything you may want on this subject and more.

Answer (score 2):

The math you need for your problem can be found in chapter 9 of "Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision", which happens to be freely available online: https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/hzbook2/HZepipolar.pdf.

The short answer to your problem is:
No not in this exact format. Given you are working in a 3D world, you have one degree of freedom left. As a result you need to get more information in order to eliminate this degree of freedom (e.g. by knowing the depth and/or the relation of the two squares with respect to each other, the movement of the camera...). This mainly depends on your specific situation. Anyhow, reading and understanding chapter 9 of the book should help you out here.

PS: to me it seems like your problem fits into the broader category of "baseline matching" problems. Reading around about this, in addition to epipolar geometry and the fundamental matrix, might help you out.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at the chapter you provided. Does it simplify the problem at all if the squares are always parallel to the camera and same distance (i.e. as if the scene was in 2D)?

Comment: Yes, it would. In that case projecting the points on the camera plane should suffice to know where square **a** should appear.

Comment: You'll find this in the beginning of chapter 9.

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand the transformations performed by the camera to project the 3D world in the 2D image you need to know its calibration parameters. These are basically divided into two sets:

1. **Intrensic parameters**: These are fixed parameters that are specific for each camera. They are normally represented by a Matrix called k.
2. **Extrensic parameters**: These depend on the camera position in the 3D world. Normally they are represented by two matrices: R and T where the first one represents the rotation and the second one represents the translation

In order to calibrate a camera your need some pattern (basically a set of 3D points which coordinates are known). There are several examples for this in OpenCV library which provides support to perform the camera calibration:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html

Once you have your camera calibrated you can transform from 3D to 2D easily by the following equation:

Pimage = K · R · T · P3D

So it will not only depend on the position of the camera but it depends on all the calibration parameters. The following presentation go through the camera calibration details and the different steps and equations that are used during the 3D <-> Image transformations.

https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2013/cmsc426/lectures/camera-calibration.pdf

With this in mind you can project whatever 3D point to the image and get its coordinate on it. The reverse transformation is not unique since going back from 2D to 3D will give you a line instead of a unique point.